# How to close a modal form when it's sent and it changes the app's state in React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

The form's submit button is this one: `<input type="submit" className="btn btn-default" value="Vender"/>`, I know that I can add a JQuery script but I want to keep using solely React. I am not using React-bootstrap, just regular Bootstrap. I also tried adding `data-dismiss="modal"` but then it closes the modal form without changing the app's state

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<form>` element's `onSubmit` property.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    ...
</form>
```

You can close the modal and update the app state from within there.

Comment: I have

onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
   //Update app state
}

What should I add to that function then?